# Search via all Skype history

Tags: skype, sql, sqlite

How to search given string at all chat histories?
**СTRL+F** - search inside one chat, but I have a lot them, so I want find something in all saved chats?

Comment: Knowing your operating system would help!

Comment: Have you looked here? http://shop.skype.com/apps/Search-Results.html?q=search#results

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the Contact list or Recent list, simply click the contact or group you want to view the conversation history for and your conversation history is displayed.

The main.db database file where all chat history is stored. main.db is a standard SQLite database file and can be opened using any SQLite browser application. However, there is a free application, which is especially designed to read Skype’s chat and call data – [SkypeLogView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html).

The main.db file is saved in one of the following (depending on OS).

On Windows 7 + : `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Skype\[Skype User Name]`

On Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\Skype\[Skype User Name]`

Following should work on all Windows versions, you can copy it into the Run prompt:

`%APPDATA%\Skype` `\[Skype User Name]`

On Mac OS X: `Library/Application Support/Skype/[Skype User Name]`

For future, you may want to consider [SkyHistory](http://scand.com/products/skyhistory/index.html)

Comment: SkypeLogView - helps me, really nice tool.

Comment: SkyHistory still works with recent Skype. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the links to 3rd party tools. I find that search in Skype itself is lame - some older time periods in the chat sometimes are collapsed and Skype ignores them when searching. I have to scroll through the chat first and expand all collapsed periods and only then I can find some text which was previously hidden in one of those collapsed periods.

Comment: Consider replacing `[USER NAME]` with `%USERNAME%`, so that your path becomes copy/pastable.
Also, "Skype name" was ambiguous to me (thought it was Skype's version or something O_o), I 'd update to "Skype username"

Comment: Seems like the answer is outdated. Does anybody khow the way to seach Skype history in 2019?

Comment: @userlond have you got solution for search skype history?

Answer (score 7):

Writing your own SQL queries using e.g. SqliteBrowser to search the Skype database, allows for more flexibility and functionality than using a 3rd party Skype-specific tool.

For example, this query will search for a text string in all your chats, and display the (local) time the message was posted, the message itself, the name of the chat (if it has a name), and who is in the chat.

```
select DISTINCT datetime(m.timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as postedon, c.displayname as chatname, m.from_dispname as fromuser, m.body_xml as msgtext
from Messages m
INNER JOIN Conversations c ON m.convo_id = c.id
where m.body_xml LIKE '%my text%' --case insensitive
order by m.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: this isn't working (0 rows returned) on my current Skype version (7.33.0.105)

Comment: @Facundo: I just tried it again with 7.34.0.102 and it still works for me. Make sure that the "%my text%" line is changed to something you're searching for (or comment out that line).

Comment: @Facundo: I found my mistake; I was joining with the wrong table. Please try it again with the updated script above.

Answer (score 7):

[Skyperious](https://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/) also might be worth checking out.  It has a few capabilities over SkypeLogView, such as

- Import contacts from a CSV file to your Skype contacts
- View any database table and and export their data
- Change, add or delete data in any table
- Execute direct SQL queries
- Synchronize messages in two Skype databases: keep chat history up-to-date on different computers, or restore missing messages from older files into the current one
- Chat statistics

Comment: I just used Skyperious again to search for a word that I knew I used in a conversation years ago, but I forgot the person I was talking to.  That would have taken ages to do if I attempted to click on each individual name and search the term.  Thank God.

Answer (score 3):

I recently found a nice online tool for browsing Skype history: http://www.skypebrowser.com

Seems to be the best solution if you're not concerned about privacy issues.

Answer (score 1):

SkyHistory did not work for me - seems like it was not designed for 68MB of skype logs : )

One of the most powerful approaches is a also very simple - just use SQLite client. Here I wrote a simple manual: http://jehy.ru/articles/2014/05/26/searching-through-skype-history/

> If you have more then 300 contacts and they have overlapping conversations – you understand that it’s impossible to find anything with simple Ctrl+F approach.
>
> Fortunately, Skype uses SQLite database and we can make a direct connect to it and search there directly. So, you need to:
>
> 1) Download SQLite client (i used http://sqlitebrowser.org/ but you
>   can install any client you like) 2) Find your history file as it is
>   decribed on skype web site:
>
> Hold down the Windows key The Windows key on your keyboard, then press
>   R to bring up the Run window. If you are using a touch screen device
>   on Windows 8, you can bring up the Run window from the Search charm.
>   Type %appdata%\Skype into the Run window and press Enter. Open the
>   folder named after your Skype Name. Find the main.db file in the
>   folder, this file is your chat history.
>
> 3) Use your SQLite client to open this file. 4) Open database table
>   “messages” 5) Use any SQL queries you want to search for message you
>   need. Here’s an example of me searching for “git” word in
>   conversations – but there are many field that you can use for
>   searching and ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Following queries on main.db works for me:

Finds group chats

```
SELECT DISTINCT datetime(m.timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), c.id, m.author, m.body_xml FROM
messages m
JOIN conversations c ON c.id = m.convo_id
WHERE c.type = 2 AND
m.body_xml NOT NULL
ORDER BY m.timestamp ASC
```

Finds private chat with your buddy

```
SELECT DISTINCT datetime(m.timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), m.author, m.body_xml FROM
messages m
JOIN conversations c ON c.id = m.convo_id
WHERE m.body_xml NOT NULL AND
c.identity LIKE '%YOUR.BUDDY.NAME.HERE%' --case insensitive
ORDER BY m.timestamp ASC
```

In private chat with your buddy finds given word

```
SELECT DISTINCT datetime(m.timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), m.author, m.body_xml FROM
messages m
JOIN conversations c ON c.id = m.convo_id
WHERE c.identity = 'YOUR.BUDDY.NAME.HERE' AND
m.body_xml NOT NULL AND
m.body_xml LIKE '%YOUR.SEARCHED.WORD.HERE%' --case insensitive
ORDER BY m.timestamp ASC
```

PS: sometimes your buddy name might be different than it is displayed in skype, so check this one first:

```
SELECT identity, displayname FROM conversations
```

and pick up one from `identity` column

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all answers here are outdated

> As of Skype version 8.50 or thereabouts, conversation history is no longer available on the user machine. Previously, all chat history was kept in a local SQLite database file. With the new versions, chat messages seem to be kept on cloud servers only, retrieved on command by the Skype client, unavailable to external tools.

Taken from [here](https://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/).

The only slow option seems to be scrolling through all chats in time ...